# Getting an array of connected items

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a category array like:

```
0: {_id: 1, image: "/static/categories/apartment.png", name: "apartments", properties: Array(2), rootCategoryId: null, …}
1: {_id: 2, image: "/static/categories/car.png", name: "cars", properties: Array(1), rootCategoryId: null, …}
2: {_id: 3, image: "/static/categories/dress.png", name: "cloathes", properties: Array(1), rootCategoryId: null, …}
3: {_id: 4, image: "/static/categories/fridge.png", name: "electronicsAndGadgets", properties: Array(1), rootCategoryId: null, …}
4: {_id: 99, image: "/static/categories/phone.png", name: "smartPhones", properties: Array(0), rootCategoryId: 4, …}
5: {_id: 100, image: "/static/categories/shoes.png", name: "shoes", properties: Array(0), rootCategoryId: 3, …}
6: {_id: 1000, image: null, name: "sneakers", properties: Array(0), rootCategoryId: 100, …}
7: {_id: 1001, image: null, name: "sandals", properties: Array(0), rootCategoryId: 100, …}
```

In other words.

```
Root category (image: '../png', rootCategoryId: null)

Sub categories (image: '../png' OR null, rootCategoryId: ID)


1 (root) -> 100 (sub1) -> 1000 (sub2)
```

Since, root always has a picture, and sometimes sub categories do not have a picture, I am trying to do reverse search until I find a picture.
Created this function to get a related categories, but I think it could be done better:

```
    export const getCategoryImageByByCategoryId = id => {
      if (!store) return null;
      const getCategory = (id) => _.find(categoriesList, category => category._id === id);
      const state = store.getState();
      const categoriesList = state.categories.categoriestList;
      let currentCategory = getCategory(id);
      const result = [currentCategory];
      while (currentCategory !== null) {
        const nextId = currentCategory.rootCategoryId;
        if (!nextId) {
          currentCategory = null;
        } else {
          currentCategory = getCategory(nextId);
          result.push(currentCategory);
        }
      }
      return result;
    };
```

Whats the best way of doing this? Should use reduce fn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an object with `_id` as key and call the function until you get an image.

```js
function getCategoryImageByByCategoryId(id) {
    return reference[id].image
        || getCategoryImageByByCategoryId(reference[id].rootCategoryId);
}

var data = [{ _id: 1, image: "/static/categories/apartment.png", name: "apartments", properties: [], rootCategoryId: null }, { _id: 2, image: "/static/categories/car.png", name: "cars", properties: [], rootCategoryId: null }, { _id: 3, image: "/static/categories/dress.png", name: "cloathes", properties: [], rootCategoryId: null }, { _id: 4, image: "/static/categories/fridge.png", name: "electronicsAndGadgets", properties: [], rootCategoryId: null }, { _id: 99, image: "/static/categories/phone.png", name: "smartPhones", properties: [], rootCategoryId: 4 }, { _id: 100, image: null, name: "shoes", properties: [], rootCategoryId: 3 }, { _id: 1000, image: null, name: "sneakers", properties: [], rootCategoryId: 100 }, { _id: 1001, image: null, name: "sandals", properties: [], rootCategoryId: 100 }],
    reference = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        r[o._id] = o;
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(getCategoryImageByByCategoryId(1000));
```

Comment: this assumes that the array is sorted

Answer (score 1):

Note that a call of the following:

```
const getCategory = (id) => _.find(categoriesList, category => category._id === id);
```

Represents an iteration that might well have to iterate the whole array (worst case). This has a *O(n)* time complexity.

Instead prepare a map so you can identify a category by its id in constant time:

```
let map = new Map(state.categories.categoriesList.map(category => [category._id, category]));
```

As long as this list does not change, you should not have to repeat creating this map either. Once you have it, you can just retrieve the category by id as follows:

```
category = map.get(id);
```

Secondly, from your question it is not clear that you really need an array as return value, and one that contains the *whole* path to the very root. If your concern is really to get the image, then you should not need that array, and you should exit the loop as soon as you found a non-`null` value for `category.image`, and return that.

Comment: that is true, I do not need an array to be returned, instead it should return a string with the image url, it's just the first thing that came to my mind was to get all related categories, and then search again for the first with an image

Comment: I would never have a huge array of categories, maxing to a 100 I believe, which shouldn't be an issue, but thank you very much. The concept of using Map to get values in a huge list is a life saver

Comment: If you only have to deal with 100 entries, then there is indeed not much to gain. Then, I must ask, what makes you come and ask the question? It can't be that you ran into performance problems...

Comment: implementation problems, wondering whats the most neat way of solving it, in terms of writing the code

Comment: If it is about "neat", then this would be a more suitable question for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). But if you have implementation problems, then please focus your question on what those problems are.